# is the set of skew-symmetric matrices with positive Pfaffians path connected?

Tags: linear-algebra, gn.general-topology, lie-groups

Is the set of real $2n \times 2n$ skew-symmetric matrices having positive Pfaffians path connected?

By definition, the Pfaffian is a polynomial in the entries $a_{ij}$ ($i<j$) such that $Pf(A)^2=\det A$, and $Pf(J_n)=1$, where
$$J_n=\begin{pmatrix} 0_n & I_n \\ -I_n & 0n \end{pmatrix}.$$

Comment: For odd dimension, this intersection is empty.

Comment: I really meant even dimension.

Comment: And also note that for $n=2$ its true.

Comment: Wait, this seems to be false for $n=2$. $\det \left( \begin{smallmatrix} 0 & x \\ -x & 0 \end{smallmatrix} \right) = x^2 \geq 0$ so all invertible $2 \times 2$ skew symmetric matrices are in $GL_n^+$, and there are two connected components, $x>0$ and $x<0$. A more reasonable conjecture would be that the set of $(2n) \times (2n)$ skew symmetric matrices with positive Pfaffian is path connected.

Comment: Why for $n=2$ is true? The space of $2$-dimensional skew symmetric matrices is a  a copy of $\mathbb{R}$ linearly embedded in  $\textrm{Mat}(2, \, \mathbb{R})$. The only rank $2$ skew-symmetric matrix with non-positive determinant is the zero matrix, so the intersection with the positive component of $\textrm{GL}(2, \, \mathbb{R})$ is precisely $\mathbb{R} - \{0\}$, which is not path connected.

Comment: yes, of course. Sorry. @david you formulated the right question. Thanks

Comment: The question is still ill-asked: $\sqrt{x^2}=|x|$ is always nonnegative. It's just that the definition of Pfaffian is not correct. The Pfaffian can be defined as the unique polynomial $P$ on the space of skew-symmetric matrices such that $P(A)^2=\det(A)$ for all $A$ and $P(J)=1$ where $J$ is a suitable choice of matrix (say made of $2\times 2$ blocks $(0,1)(-1,0)$).

Answer (score 8):

The answer is 'yes', because this space is the homogeneous space $\mathrm{GL}^+(2n,\mathbb{R})/\mathrm{Sp}(n,\mathbb{R})$, which is connected.

Here is more detail:  Let $J_n$ be the $2n$-by-$2n$ matrix that is $n$ diagonally placed copies of the $2$-by-$2$ matrix $\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\-1&0\end{pmatrix}$.  Then $J_n$ is a skew-symmetric matrix with positive Pfaffian.  Any other skew-symmetric $2n$-by-$2n$ matrix $A$ with nonzero determinant can be written in the form
$$
A = aJ_na^{T}
$$ 
where $a$ is an element of $\mathrm{GL}(2n,\mathbb{R})$ that is unique up to right multiplication by an element of
$$
\mathrm{Sp}(n,\mathbb{R}) = \left\{ a\in\mathrm{GL}(2n,\mathbb{R}) \ |\ \  aJ_na^{T} = J_n\right\}.
$$
Finally, note that $\mathrm{Pf}(A) = \det(a)$, so $\mathrm{Pf}(A)>0$ if and only if $a\in\mathrm{GL}^+(2n,\mathbb{R})$.  Thus, your space of matrices is identified with the homogeneous space $\mathrm{GL}^+(2n,\mathbb{R})/\mathrm{Sp}(n,\mathbb{R})$, which is connected, since $\mathrm{GL}^+(2n,\mathbb{R})$ is connected.

**Remark:**  Actually, the Pfaffian is *not* defined as 'the' square root of $\det(A)$, as this is ambiguous.  It just happens that the Pfaffian of $A$ is a polynomial in the entries of $A$ whose square is the determinant of $A$ (which is why it is interesting).

Comment: Great! This is also path-connected because? Sorry for this silly question. I am not a mathematician. Just a physics student.

Comment: If I understand your question, you are asking whether connected implies path-connected.  The answer is yes, because it's a (smooth) manifold (of dimension $2n^2-n$), and a manifold is path-connected if and only if it is connected.